# generate list of source files not registered in any project

Tags: visual-c++

There is large MSVC c++ solution. Consisting of dozens of projects.
How can I generate list of .h,.cpp files that break one of the following consistency rules:
- file (.cpp,.h) exists but is not registsred in any project
- file (.cpp,.h) is included but is not registered in the project
- project registers source file that is not in projects's directory

The directory of the solution is simple.It is one-level set of directories in solution base dir, every directory is one project, if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution you have to do that is to write a script in order to walk through all your project directories and to read all your .vcproj files (XML like files).

If you use Python, I advice you to use the xml.dom and xml.dom.minidom modules in order to read the .vcproj files and the os.walk function to walk through your project directories.

The .vcproj file protoype necessary data for you is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<VisualStudioProject Name=......>
  <Files>
    <Filter Filter="cpp;c;cc;cxx;........>
      <File RelativePath="YOUR.cpp file here"/>
      ...
    </Filter>
    <Filter Filter="h;hpp;hxx;........>
      <File RelativePath="YOUR.h file here"/>
      ...
    </Filter>
  </Files>
</VisualStudioProject>
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of VS are you using?

Not sure what you mean by "registered in any project", but here's a starting point:
You can obtain a list of all .h and .cpp files by doing (recursive) directory listings from the root directory. Since the solution and the project files are just .xml files(in later versions of VS at least), you can just use regular expressions to pull out all the referenced .h and .cpp files and then cross reference the list you got doing directory listings with the ones you can parse from project files. In your case your simple directory structure makes the searching a little simpler.

If by your second point you mean "included by another source or header" then I guess you have to read all .h and .cpp files and search for #include statements, but this would make the program a little more complex.